# Custom post type rewrite slug

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type with name `Landing Page` and I want to remove the slug of the CPT from the URL. For example:

Default WP behaviour: http://somedomain.com/landing-page/test/

Need URL: http://somedomain.com/test/

To accomplish it, I am using the `register_post_type` function with rewrite params like:

Solution Tried 1:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/','with_front' => false),`

Solution Tried 2:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => false,'with_front' => false),`

But, it is not working. Can anyone help me to solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same question and answer that works here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls#answer-282040

Comment: @AlexVand I already tried it. But it's creating an issue with the WP slug creation default functionality.